# I could not draw a perfect round in iOS ,either cornerRadius or User UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, cornerradius

I draw a Round View with *cornerRadius*, I set its frame `CGRectMake(0,0,90,90),cornerRadius = 45` ,and `masksToBounds = YES`.

Then I make it transform **scale 1.3**, but it is not a perfect round. You can see clearly that its middle top, middle bottom, middle left, middle right has some *sawtooth*，it is not perfect round.

I don't know why.

```
ratio = SCREEN_WIDTH /414.;

UIVisualEffect *effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
self.backGroundView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:effect ];
[self.backGroundView setFrame:CGRectMake(0 *ratio, 0 *ratio, 90 *ratio, 90 *ratio)];
self.backGroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.4];
self.backGroundView.layer.cornerRadius = self.backGroundView.width /2 ;
self.backGroundView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

[self addSubview:self.backGroundView];


CAMediaTimingFunction *clunk = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

CGAffineTransform startValue2 = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGAffineTransform endValue2 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
CABasicAnimation *animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation2.delegate = self;
animation2.duration = .4;
animation2.timingFunction = clunk;
animation2.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:startValue2];
animation2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:endValue2];
animation2.repeatCount = 1;
self.backGroundView.layer.affineTransform = endValue2;
[self.backGroundView.layer addAnimation:animation2 forKey:nil];
```

Comment: i set size 117 117 and make cornerRadius 58.5 has the same problem

Comment: Can you provide complete executable playground code for that problem. To me it looks fine, what happens if you put `maskToBounds=false`.

Comment: Assuming your view is square.In your scale method write, `your_view.layer.cornerRadius = your_view.frame.size.width/2`

Comment: start big and shrink down.

Comment: @ luk2302 2 ,my code is below. it miss half pixel in four postion , you may not see it only after u let a  cashapelayer draw stroke color at its edge. it is obvious while the shapelayer is drawing.